# Are there any Indicators that this specific Integer Linear Program is solvable in polynomial time

Tags: polynomial-time, integer-programming

I have a pretty complex problem and I am using a rather complex ILP to solve it. In a special case of the problem the ILP is reduced to the following "simple" ILP. Additionally, I know that for this special case there exist polynomial time algorithms.

We have two sets of variables $V$ and $E$. $E$ can be split into three disjoint sets $E=N\cup P\cup C$. The ILP is given "in logic" as:

\begin{align*}
\min \sum_{v\in V} v\cdot a(v)&+\sum_{e\in E} e\cdot p(e)\\
v_e^l\oplus v_e^r&=e  &e\in N\\
v_e^l\oplus 1&=e      &e\in P\\
v_e^l\oplus 0&=e      &e\in C
\end{align*}

Where $\oplus$ denotes XOR. The last two constraints reduce to $e=\neg v_e^l$ and $e=v_e^l$.
The XOR can be written as linear constraints by a standard transformation and we get:

\begin{align*}
\min \sum_{v\in V} v\cdot a(v)&+\sum_{e\in E} e\cdot p(e)\\
v_e^l+ v_e^r+e&\leq 2  &e\in N\\
-v_e^l- v_e^r+e&\leq 0 &e\in N\\
-v_e^l+ v_e^r-e&\leq 0  &e\in N\\
v_e^l- v_e^r-e&\leq 0  &e\in N\\
v_e^l-e&=0  &e\in P\\
v_e^l+(1-e)&=0  &e\in C
\end{align*}

I know that every $e$ is in exactly one XOR constraint (so either in 4 or 1 linear constraint) and every $t$ is in exactly three XOR constraints.

My question is the following: Is this ILP solvable in polynomial time or not (is the LP solution Integer)? Are there any indicators that this may or may not be the case?

I'm aware that total unimodularity is a sufficient condition, but I'm not sure if the matrix is total unimodular and if so how i could show it.